# How to understand $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} I\{X>n\}$, where $I$ is an indicator function?

Tags: probability, statistics, summation, random-variables

I am having difficulties to interpret $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} I\{X>n\}$$
where $X$ is a discrete random variable and we define
$ I\{X>n\} = \begin{cases}
1, &\text{if } X>n\newline
0, &\text{if } X\leq n
\end{cases}
$.
Note: $X\in\mathbb{N}\cup\{0\}$.
My initial thought is to rewrite the summation in separate term ($I_{X>0} + I_{X>1} + \cdots$). But I get nothing from that.
Then I thought the summation might be equal to $X$. However, I don't know whether my intuition is right or not. If it's wrong, then I am really out of ideas.
I need some advices or hints on how to interpret such summation.

Many thanks,
S.

Comment: It might be helpful to proceed on a case-by-case basis: If $X=0$, what is the value of the sum?  If $X=1$, what is the value of the sum? And so forth.

Comment: @stochasticboy321 If $I\{X>n\} = \sum_{k = n+1}^{\infty} I\{X = k\}$, then $I\{X>n\}$ could be equal to number greater than 1, right. I'm a bit confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if $\Bbb I\{n<X\}$ is $1$ for values less than $X$ and $0$ for values of $X$ or greater, then split the series:

## $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \Bbb I\{n<X\} ~=~ \sum_{n=0}^{X-1} 1 ~+~ \sum_{n=X}^\infty 0$$

That is all.

Comment: I have never thought of that in this way. Thank you so much, now I see.

Answer (score 1):

$\sum_n 1_{ \{ \omega | X(\omega) > n \} } (t) = X(t)$.

Basically it counts how many of the sets $\{ \omega | X(\omega) > n \} $
that $t$ is in and this is equal to the number of $n$s in $\{0,1,...\}$ for which $x(t) > n$, which, in turn, is $X(t)$.